# scrolling bug that i cant figure out

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to create a mobile website and when you click on the image on the right to display the navigation and scroll to the right there is white space that I can't figure out how to get rid of.

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7SZq/1/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <!--end div logo-->
    <div id="rectangle"><a id="show" href="#"><img src="images/rectangle.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end div header-->
<div class="nav">Hello!</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have logo and rectangle absolute positioned? Header is width:100% and it has padding so its width is 100%+10px . Reduce its width or add box-sizing: border-box

Comment: where is image to click in your fiddle...........!!!!!!????

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  The problem you were having is that padding doesn't only put space in between the element and its children, in most browsers it also increases the size of the element on each side by that much.  The result is that the #header element has a width of 100% and 5px of padding on each side, making it 100%+10px wide, as one of the comments said.

To fix this problem while maintaining 5px of space between the border of #header and any child elements, you can place a block display wrapper (div) immediately inside #header enclosing all of its descendants and applying 5px of padding.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v7SZq/3/**

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div style="padding:5px;">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <!--end div logo-->
            <div id="rectangle"><a id="show" href="#"><img src="images/rectangle.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end div header-->
<div class="nav">Hello!</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#header {
    background:#2B3990;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ec8123
}
#logo {
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
}
#rectangle {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:;
    position:absolute;
    left:85%;
    top:13px;
}
.nav {
    width:85%;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    background:#000;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nav").hide();
    $("#show").show();

    $('#show').click(function () {
        $(".nav").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

**Finally, a quick refresh on how padding works in most browsers:**

[image]

The space you see in the "Padding" zone in this image is ADDING to the size of the div, not just offsetting the child elements.

Answer (score -1):

Remove padding from #header

```
#header {
/*padding:5px;*/
background:#2B3990;
height:40px;
width:100%;
position:relative;
border-bottom:1px solid #ec8123
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7SZq/2/)

Comment: This alone doesn't solve his problem if he needs the internal padding in the #header element, and I do assume it is there for a reason.

Comment: No, that problem is still there in your fiddle.